# React Native Android websocket connection erroring with 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, react-native, websocket

I am trying to set up a simple websocket connection in my React Native app. It is returning the following error in Android: `{"isTrusted": false, "message": "Expected HTTP 101 response but was '401 Unauthorized'"}`. The websocket is opening fine in iOS, and using a websocket connection that does not require my user to be authenticated works (my user is authenticated for this server but it still say I'm not authorized).

Here is the relevant code in my app:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${DOMAIN}/api/stream/all`)
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('websocket open') // --> iOS
    }
    ws.onerror = e => {
      console.log('error', e) // --> Android
    }
  }, [])
```

Changing it to this works on Android:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://echo.websocket.events/.ws`)
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('websocket open') // --> Android & iOS
    }
    ws.onerror = e => {
      console.log('error', e)
    }
  }, [])
```

Any idea why authentication is not working? Is there some Android config that needs to be changed so the authentication that already happened for this domain on `https` gets to the websocket connection somehow?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? We just started with React Native / Expo, and we are seeing this same thing. Trying our app with Expo Go has this issue, and Android devices are unable to open websocket.

Comment: @tnurmi Yes, I ended up sending the session cookie in the headers. I will post my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing it to this (added session cookie to headers for Android):

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${DOMAIN}/api/stream/all`)
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('websocket open') // --> it works!
    }
} else {
    const ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${DOMAIN}/api/stream/all`, '', { headers: {Cookie: sessionCookie } })
    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log('websocket open') // --> it works!
    }
}
```

I got the session cookie from the response after the user logged in and kept that in state to be used in the websocket connection: `const sessionCookie = res.headers.get('set-cookie')`. This solution may not work for everyone if login doesn't work the same way for you, but it may help someone.